# Can data-* attributes be boolean like checked?

Tags: html

They do seem to work that way in chrome and ff but is this intended functionality? eg can I rely on them continuing to work without an explicit value?

example:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-mychecked>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, `data` attributes can be used as booleans. If the data attribute has a non-existing value then the property value is an empty string. If the data attribute doesn't exist at all then the property value is `undefined`.

```
var isChecked = (typeof checkbox.dataset.mychecked !== 'undefined');
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xu19n3pd/**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked data-mychecked data-foo="bar">

var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
console.log(checkbox.dataset.mychecked); // ""
console.log(checkbox.dataset.foo); // "bar"
console.log(checkbox.dataset.idontexist); // undefined
```